# CollectionViewCell, MapView and Custom Annotation

Tags: swift, swift4, mkmapview, uicollectionviewcell, mkannotation

My project contains a collectionView with a map **in each cell**..

[image: map in cell]

I'm trying to customize the marker (annotation) but it does not work.

This is how I do :

1/ Interesting functions in my class **ListeIncidentsController** :

```
class ListeIncidentsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

...

// for each cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCelluleIncident", for: indexPath) as! collectionViewCelluleIncident
    let Incident = TabListeIncidents[indexPath.section] // section, pas row car on a mis les items en sections
    cell.displayContent(Incident: Incident, isSelected: cell.isSelected)
    return cell
}

...

}
```

2/ Interesting functions in my class **collectionViewCelluleIncident** :

```
class collectionViewCelluleIncident : UICollectionViewCell {

    ...

    func displayContent(Incident: Incident, isSelected : Bool){
        let TabCoordonnees = Incident.Coordonnee.split(separator: ",")
        let coordonnees = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(TabCoordonnees[0])!, longitude: Double(TabCoordonnees[1])!)
        let rayon : Double = Incident.Rayon

        // Add my custom Annotation
        let pinIncident = MyCustomPointAnnotation(TypeDePoint: .Incident) // class : CustomPointAnnotation.swift
        pinIncident.title = Incident.Adresse
        pinIncident.subtitle = "Rayon : "+String(Incident.Rayon)+"m"
        pinIncident.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordonnees.latitude, longitude: coordonnees.longitude)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(pinIncident) // add my annotation

        ...etc etc
    }

    ...
}
```

3/ Interesting functions in **extensions** :

```
extension collectionViewCelluleIncident : MKMapViewDelegate {

    ...

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let identifier = "MyCustomPin"
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.image = nil

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "my_custom_icon")
        }
        else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
            annotationView?.image = nil
        }

        return annotationView
    }
}
```

4/ This is how my items are connected

[image: delegate]

My problem is that I never go in my extension (mapView / ViewFor) so my annotation is never customized :/

I think I was wrong somewhere but I do not know where ..

Do you have an idea  ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell from the drawing, but it seems like you have set the collectionView itself to be the delegate of the mapView, where you have implemented the delegate callback in the cell, as far as I can tell. Have you tried setting mapView.delegate = self (in collectionView cell)